# How to use SSRS inside SPA framework (Durandal)?

Tags: reporting-services, durandal

I am using SSRS Reporting service as a part of my project and i am doing this project using ASP.net with SPA framework (durandal). My question is that is it possible to embed SSRS inside SPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS reports are saved as rdl or rdlc files which are just xml files.

SPAs are run in the browser using JavaScript.

SSRS reports in order to be rendered into a presentable report they need to be run on a machine that has the .NET framework.  This is usually a web server or a report server.

What you can do is create a web service that will render the reports for you and return them back in a format you want, like pdf, img, or html.  Then have your SPA just call those web services to get whatever reports you want.